# UltraCombo Filter Does Not Work

Tags: infragistics, ultracombo

I have the following application code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim datatableCombo = New DataTable
        datatableCombo.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        datatableCombo.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({0, ""})
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({1, "123"})
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({2, "234"})
        datatableCombo.Rows.Add({3, "456"})

        UltraCombo1.DataSource = datatableCombo

        Dim datatableGrid = New DataTable
        datatableGrid.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        datatableGrid.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        SsiGrid1.DataSource = datatableGrid

        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.GroupByBox.Hidden = True
        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.True
        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.TemplateOnBottom

        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").EditorComponent = UltraCombo1
        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.EditAndSelectText
        SsiGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("ID").Style = ColumnStyle.DropDownValidate
    End Sub

    Private Sub UltraCombo1_InitializeLayout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs) Handles UltraCombo1.InitializeLayout
        UltraCombo1.ValueMember = "ID"
        UltraCombo1.DisplayMember = "Name"

        Dim band As UltraGridBand = Me.UltraCombo1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)

        Dim position As Integer = 0
        band.Columns("ID").Hidden = False
        band.Columns("ID").Header.VisiblePosition = position
        position += 1
        band.Columns("Name").Hidden = False
        band.Columns("Name").Header.VisiblePosition = position
        position += 1

        band.Override.AllowRowFiltering = DefaultableBoolean.False
        band.Override.RowFilterMode = RowFilterMode.AllRowsInBand

        band.ColumnFilters("ID").FilterConditions.Clear()
        band.ColumnFilters("ID").FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.NotEquals, 0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I believe this should make it so that the combo box does not show the zero row unless you actually type a zero. But when I run it, it does show the zero row. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. This code should hide the zero from the drop down list. One possible reason for this error could be if you did not actually handling InitializeLayout event of the combo. You can easily check this by open the designer, select the combo and check in properties window if UltraCombo1_InitializeLayout is selected against InitializeLayout event.
You can also put a breakpoint somewhere in the event handler and see if you ever reach it.